# How to begin with HM for HEVC further?

Tags: video, video-processing, video-codecs, hevc

I am new to HEVC.I am doing research on HEVC in HM software. i have successfully run a demo seeing Vcodex.com using ./TAppEncoder -c encoder_randomaccess.cfg -c xxxx.cfg. I understand .cfg is the configuration file which contains all the detailed info parameters.

As a new learner of HM for HEVC, my doubt is how to proceed further in learning more about using and understanding HM software for HEVC.

or, what and where is the change i should make if i have to do further research.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines but about study & career advice.

Answer (score 0):

first, you must learn all the part of HEVC, to know how does HEVC working. and you can read some papers about HEVC. at that time, I think you can have some interesting things in some part, and you can make your own ideal...

At this time, I think you just can run HEVC S/W. it's meaning nothing.

HEVC have amount of part to study. you can search papers for HEVC, the result of the number  of paper is more than 1000.